# push notifications not handled by onMessage if received when app closed using IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using MFP 7.0.0.00-20150907-1450 and building a hybrid app targeting iOS and Android.
We're using the ["send bulk messages" REST API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/apiref/r_restapi_send_bulk_messages_post.html) to send broadcast messages.

We've implemented [`WL.Client.Push.onMessage`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.Push.html?cp=SSHS8R_7.0.0%2F9-0-0-1-8) in our app, and as long as the app is running when the notification is received, it handles the message.
If the application is closed when the notification reaches the phone, the message payload doesn't seem to get to our `onMessage` implementation.

This behavior is identical between iOS and Android.

I suspect there's a timing issue between our `onMessage` function being assigned and when the MFP framework is trying to pass the the message into our app.
Some pointers on how we might get the message handled in the case where it was received when the app was closed would be great!

(Below are some details of our setup.)

---

We're using Angular and **had** this in our main app module:

```
if (angular.isDefined(window.WL) && angular.isDefined(window.WL.Client.Push)) {
  window.WL.Client.Push.onMessage = function (props, payload) {
    console.log('Received push notification in client', JSON.stringify(props), JSON.stringify(payload));
    $rootScope.$broadcast('pushNotification', props, payload);
  };
}
```

After noticing this ("You must declare it outside any function.") in the docs for `onMessage`, I've moved the assignment out to the top of a JavaScript file, outside of even an IIFE. This function doesn't seem to be called, certainly there's no logging and the variable remains undefined:

```
var lastPushMessage;
function pushMessageRecorder(props, payload) {
  lastPushMessage = {
    props: props,
    payload: payload
  };
  console.log('MFP: push received: ' + JSON.stringify(lastPushMessage, null, 2));
}
WL.Client.Push.onMessage = pushMessageRecorder;
```

Our security test (users don't have to log in, just have a app packaged with our keys):

```
<customSecurityTest name="customTests">
  <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1" />
  <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1" />
  <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1" />
  <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1" />
  <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1" />
  <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2" />
</customSecurityTest>
```

Comment: Lets simplify the question. Does it work without the angular code? If it does, then this question is not about Worklight but about angular.

Comment: It's a question about worklight regardless of the use of angular. The question comes to: when does MFP try to pass the push data to the app, and what are the considerations an implementer must be aware of so that the onMessage function is defined in time? (I'll continue to investigate different configurations, but without that answer, even if I get it working in my environment, I can't be sure that it'll work on all the devices in the field.)

Comment: onMessage is called whenever the app is launched (if there is login, then after the login).

Comment: I've moved the onMessage assignment out any functions (not even in an IIFE, see updated description) - it is not being called when the app opens.

Comment: That's strange. Try updating to the latest iFix..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I've got it working.
(Mostly. If the app is not running and the user swipes away the notification, or opens the app directly from the launcher, then the notification *still* doesn't show up in the app.)

There were 2 things that needed doing:

1. the assignment to `WL.Client.Push.onMessage` had to be done "outside of any function"
2. it looks like the value for the string "app_name" in `native/res/values/strings.xml` is used to locate the app from the push service and make sure the message comes through

The second point still doesn't really make sense to me, but it looks like the intent-filter action `android:name` value in `AndroidManifest.xml` is built using these values:

```
{AndroidManifest.xml:/manifest[@package]}.{res/values/strings.xml:/resources/string[@name="app_name"]}.NOTIFICATION
```

Since the `app_name` value is used to build the notification qualifier, it can't have any spaces, which is not so nice for the name of your app that's displayed on the phone.

I've worked around that by adding another variable to the `strings.xml` file (although I could have just hard coded the name in the `AndroidManifest.xml` too, and then use that variable as my label.

Here's what's working:

`res/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
  <string name="app_label">My App</string>
  <string name="push_notification_title">My App</string>
  <!-- ... -->
</resources>
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.MyProject" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">  
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>  
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="false"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Push permissions -->  
    <permission android:name="com.MyProject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="com.MyProject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
    <application android:label="@string/app_label" android:icon="@drawable/icon"> 
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name=".MyApp" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="com.MyProject.MyApp.NOTIFICATION"/>  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>  
        <!-- Preference Activity  -->  
        <activity android:name="com.worklight.common.WLSettingActivity" android:label="Worklight Settings"/>  
        <!-- UI Activity for displaying native dialogs  -->  
        <activity android:name="com.worklight.wlclient.ui.UIActivity"/>  
        <!-- Push service  -->  
        <!-- In order to use the c2dm library, an application must declare a class with the name C2DMReceiver, in its own package, extending com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver
            It must also include this section in the manifest, replacing "com.google.android.apps.chrometophone" with its package name. -->  
        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService"/>  
        <service android:name=".ForegroundService"/>  
        <!-- Only google service can send data messages for the app. If permission is not set - any other app can generate it -->  
        <receiver android:name="com.worklight.androidgap.push.WLBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"> 
            <!-- Receive the actual message -->  
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>  
                <category android:name="com.MyProject"/>
            </intent-filter>  
            <!-- Receive the registration id -->  
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>  
                <category android:name="com.MyProject"/> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver> 
    </application> 
</manifest>
```